# Generic term for importing or calling another file?

Tags: terminology

Generically, in the software world, what's the term one would use to describe the following functionality?

- css: @import
- php: include
- ruby: require
- etc.
- etc.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are looking for. What you are talking is part of the technique that facilitates the use of the same code on multiple occasions. This facility existed in the earliest assemblers. Later the word _reuse_ became widespread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a generic term for the kinds of things which are described in the question.  The terminology depends on the context for things like this.  Just as your question suggests, if you are talking about CSS you would probably use the term "import".  If you are talking about C or PHP you would probably use the world "include".  If you were talking about Groovy or Java you would probably use the word "import".